# Is Spring SimpMessagingTemplate thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, spring-websocket

We are using the Spring WebSocket library for sending events to clients. 
We are using the org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate object to send messages - simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend()

Is SimpMessagingTemplate thread safe? The source code shows that it internally uses another class- org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel. 
Is MessageChannel thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both if them are tread-safe because they don't change any internal state.

What make you to think otherwise? 
Maybe you need to dig farther what it is used after already and there is an issue?